# rsync not skipping untouched files

Tags: linux, rsync, scp

I transferred about 300GB of files with scp from one server to another. Sadly I forgot the -r option, so part of the files that were in subdirectories were not copied. I verified that the files that were copied are the same with md5sum.

Now I want to copy the other files with rsync. The problem is, that rsync wants to send everything again. It doesn't skip the files that are already copied. It creates new files for every existing file and then replaces the existing one with the new one. I use rsync with -arvx. What do I need to do those files are skipped?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  --ignore-existing       skip updating files that exist on receiver
> ```
>
> http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: I thought this was the default action?

Comment: @user5359531 6 years late, but whatever: I was confused about that too the other day, but the default is to compare file size and modification time, whereas `--ignore-existing` skips those checks and instead just checks whether any file exists at the destination path. In other words, this flag is a bad idea unless you have some guarantee that any previous interruption didn't cause a corrupt or incomplete transfer. OP mentioned having performed an md5sum check manually, so in this case it's (arguably) not an issue. Relevant question I asked: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/767886/89143)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your drive is in the FAT format? If so, you will need `--modify-window=1` to accommodate the time stamp rounding. See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461283/why-modify-window-1-when-using-rsync-command) for more explanation about this issue.

Comment: +1 Alternatively, the timestamp issue can also be side-stepped by specifying `--size-only` to make rsync compare only file size of source and destination, instead of the default of having *both* size *and* modification time compared.